# Define decimal places of numbers based on user entry

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

In **Cells B7:D12** a `report` of the `actual-budget-performance` over the last `4 months` is created based on the `data base` in **Cells L7:N12**.

To have a better presentation of the numbers the user can decide in **Cell D2** if they should be shown for example in `1.000`.
In addition, the user can also decide in **Cell D3** how many `decimal places` should be displayed.

To apply these user entries to the `report` I have the following formula in **Cells C9:D12**:

```
=FIXED((M9/$D$2),$D$3,FALSCH)
```

All this works fine.

---

Now, I want to create a chart in **Cells G6:I14** based on the values **Cells C9:D12** which does not work. The reason for this is probably that the `FIXED` function changes the `numbers` in **Cells C9:D12** to `text`.

Therefore, I tried to solve the issue with this formula:     `=VALUE(FIXED((M9/$D$2),$D$3,FALSCH))`

This formula changes the `text` back to a `number` but also eliminates the user entry in **Cell D3** which defines the `decimal places`.

Is there a solution so the `decimal places` can be manually defined by the user and the `chart` can also be created?

---

*I know I could create a seperate data base for the chart in which the values from **Cells C9:D12** are converted back to `numbers` but I would prefer a solution without this workaround.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`=ROUND(range, digits)`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/round.php) formula in place of the `FIXED()` and it should work.

[image]

Comment: Hi Rawplus, I tried this formula but it is limited to the pre-defined decimal places in the format cell menu. For example, if I define decimal places 2 in the format cell menu (as in your example) and the user wants to see 4 places and enters a 4 into Cell D3 it still only shows 2 decimal places and does not automatically adjust to 4.

Comment: Ah sorry if that's the case, just use the general formatting. Check my edit